# Read only view using sharepoint designer 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

I have to create a read only view using SharePoint Designer 2010.
When user submits the form it has to switch to that read only view.

Could some one suggest as to how to make the view read only and also to switch between views using SharePoint Designer 2010.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You can create the form in infopath and create same views of your form:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/infopath-help/add-delete-and-switch-views-pages-in-a-form-HA101732801.aspx

and activate the version control in the list

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HUDRfhcL18U